# Entity type ' ' is defined with a single key property, but 3 values were passed to the 'DbSet.Find' method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

When im trying to update my 'StaffAssets' Table im getting below mentioned error.
'Entity type 'StaffAssets' is defined with a single key property, but 3 values were passed to the 'DbSet.Find' method.'

[image]

This is my update function

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAssetsDetailsAsync(int current = 4)
        {
            ShowAssetName = new SelectList(_context.Assets, "assetname", "assetname");
            if (ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("StaffAssets") == ModelValidationState.Valid)
            {
                var staffassets = await _context.StaffAssets.FindAsync(StaffAssets.StaffID,StaffAssets.EmpID,StaffAssets.StaffAssetName);
                if (await TryUpdateModelAsync<StaffAssets>(
                staffassets,
                "StaffAssets",
                s => s.StaffAssetName, s => s.IssuedQty, s => s.IssuedDate))
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                }
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                //when add works, then +1 ,means next tab
                currentTab = current;
                TempData["EmpID"] = StaffAssets.EmpID;
                TempData["StaffID"] = StaffAssets.StaffID;
                ShowStaffAssets = _context.StaffAssets.Where(c => c.StaffID == StaffAssets.StaffID).OrderBy(c => c.StaffAssetName).AsNoTracking().ToList();
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                currentTab = current;
                return Page();
            }
        }
```

This is StaffAssets Model Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Contractor_HRMS.Models
{
    public class StaffAssets
    {
        //--- Staff Id ---//
        [Key]
        public int StaffID { get; set; }

        //--- Emp Id ---//  
        
        [Display(Name = "Employee ID*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string EmpID { get; set; }

        //--- Asset Name ---//
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Asset")]
        [Display(Name = "Asset Name *"), StringLength(100)]
        public string StaffAssetName { get; set; }

        //--Issued Quantity ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Issued Quantity")]
        [Display(Name = "Issued Quantity*"), StringLength(10)]
        public string IssuedQty { get; set; }

        //--Issued Date ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Issued Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Issued Date*")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime IssuedDate { get; set; }

        //--Return Quantity ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Return Quantity")]
        [Display(Name = "Return Quantity*"), StringLength(10)]
        public string ReturnQty { get; set; }

        //--Return Date ---//
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Return Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Return Date*")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? ReturnDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Modified By")]
        public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Modified TimeStamp")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime? LastModifiedTimestamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my table design

[image]

Not able to figure out where im going wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like your model class defines it as having only one primary key field, which does not match your database.

Comment: for defining composite keys i need to use webapi.ryt?im getting that error.

Comment: Let's take a step back, do you know what a composite key is, and do you want or need one?, if not don't use find

Comment: @The General , I dont know what is a composite Key,i dont really need it.my staffassets table will have three keys StaffID,EmpID and StaffAssetName. So when i got the error,i added the [key] dataannotation to EmpID and StaffAssetName,then the error turned like using composite key needs some webapi call like that. I just need to update my record,thats all.

Comment: @The General instead of using findAsync() i used FirstOrDefaultAsync() method,now the error has gone,but whats is happening now is the TryUpdateModelAsync method is not working.Values are not getting updated.